# Can I use aggregate functions on PostgreSQL HStore values?

Tags: database, postgresql

Can I perform aggregate queries on values in an hstore column? For example, I'd like to determine the `SUM` of a `count` field in the store.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Yes. But values are stored as text, so you have to cast them to an appropriate data type first. So, to sum heights in inches, which are stored in an hstore in the column "other"

```
CREATE TABLE my_table (
  id integer primary key,
  other hstore
);
insert into my_table values 
(1, hstore('height_in', '72') || hstore('weight_lbs', '180')),
(2, hstore('height_in', '65') || hstore('girth_in', '42'));

select sum((other->'height_in')::integer) sum_of_height
from my_table;

sum_of_height
--
137
```

Comment: What if any one row contain value which can not be cast in integer? It will give `ERROR:  invalid input syntax for integer:` so how to get desired result by skipping that row?

Comment: @RockStar: Use a WHERE clause and a regular expression: `where (other->'height_in') ~ '^\d+$'`. The need to do this points to an error in your application code, though. Fix that.